# Mssql ORDER BY conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, t-sql

I want to make a linq query to sql query

My linq query is like that

```
 var query3 = from p in _productRepository.Table
                     join bs in query2 on p.Id equals bs.ProductId
                     orderby p.ProductTags.Count(y=>y.Id==locationId)>0
                     select p;
```

How to implement this **p.ProductTags.Count(y=>y.Id==locationId)>0** in sql query.

Comment: You can catch your qry with sql profiler tool in management studio. It will show full tsql code used with database engine even via linq qry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what your LINQ query is doing, it is ordering all the ones that have a related count in the `ProductTags` greater than 0 first and then the rest, but not ordering by the count. In that case the `ORDER BY` in the following query would be similar:

```
Select p.*
From ProductRepository As p
Join <query2> As bs On p.ID = bs.ID
Order By Case When (
    Select Count(*) 
    From ProductTags As y 
    Where y.ProductID = p.ID 
      And y.ID = @locationID) > 0 Then 1 Else 0 End;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT productRepository.Id FROM _productRepository.Table
JOIN *secondtable* 
WHERE productRepository.Id= *secondtable*.ProductId
AND  productRepository.Id = locationId
Group By by productRepository.Id
Having Count(*) > 0
ORDER BY COUNT(*)
```

From the Id fetch the other details.